# Data caching .net expires before time specified

Tags: c#, .net

I've a data cache in my application, that holds query results and expires with absolute expiration every "pair hour" i.e(08:00, 10:00, 12:00).

So:

```
 public Dictionary<int, List<Int64>> GetCacheDNAOffers()
        {
            if (_cache["DnaOffersPairs"] == null)
            {
                Dictionary<int, string> dtDNA = GetCacheActiveOffers().AsEnumerable().Select(d => new { idOferta = Convert.ToInt32(d["nof_id"]), dna = d["nof_dna"].ToString() }).ToDictionary(t => t.idOferta, t => t.dna);
                Dictionary<int, List<Int64>> lstDNA = new Dictionary<int, List<Int64>>();

                foreach (var dna in dtDNA)
                {
                    lstDNA[dna.Key] = CarregarDNA(dna.Value);
                }
                _cache.Insert("DnaOffersPairs", lstDNA, null, SetTimeCacheExpires(), TimeSpan.Zero);
            }

            return (Dictionary<int, List<Int64>>)_cache["DnaOffersPairs"];
        }
```

Function to set expiration time:

```
private DateTime SetTimeCacheExpires()
{
        try
        {

 int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            int minutes = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            int qtdhoursToExpire = 1;

            NextHours = (hour + qtdhoursToExpire);

        return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, PairHour, minutes, 1);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And functions to check "pair hours":

```
 public int PairHour
    {
        get
        {
            if (NextHours % 2 == 0)
                return NextHours;
            else
                return NextHours + 1;
        }
    }
```

Sometimes there is a problem that the cache expires, if the apllication got idle for a while, with all browsers window closed.

is there a configuration that i need to set on IIS to set that cache keep alive permanently till the end of the pre-configured cache? or is that cache configuration set correctly on code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

There is a default configuration on IIS, that determines time out on the cache if the application get idle for 20 minutes.

You have to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You should check if this is caused by IIS pool recycle. By default the app pool recycles after 20 minutes of being idle. When recycle occurs all data stored in cache will expire (the process is simply shutdown).
http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc753179(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: 29 hours(1740 minutes), not 20 minutes